# For new report creation do we need to use Cognos Framework Manager or Cognos Transformer

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

If we want to create a new Cognos report do we need to use Cognos framework manager or Cognos Transformer for the required dataset for the new report?.

Comment: Technically: No you don't, but it is recommended that you DO create a FM model or a cube. Do you have anything more specific to ask?

Comment: Hi Nick Can we use more separate packages in one report?. I mean "can we include a package with a normal tabular data FM package and an another with the Cognos Transformer created cube package"?

Comment: You can create a package that itself contains nested or multiple packages, then a report still uses one package. Without that, data from another package can still be incorporated, but it's much more difficult for the end-user/report-designer: with appropriate access they can create a SQL query against any available data source, but that bypasses much of the convenience FM provides.

Comment: Hi Nick McDermaid, if you are saying technically we don't need FM or Transformer then what other ways to create a new report?. How can be get the required datasets for the new report?

Comment: If we created a cube, how can we use the cube in a Cognos report?. First method you said to change the cube to a package and publish to the Cognos data store. My question is can we deploy the cube straightforwardly(not as a package) in the related SSIS database?. If so how can we use this cube in the Cognos reports?. By SQL statements? or by an MDX query? or some other means?